# '~/play-services-location/10.2.6/play-services-location-10.2.6.pom'

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, artifactory

Face the following error during sync with android studio.

```
Error:Could not GET 'http://192.168.2.247:8081/artifactory/list/libs-snapshot-local/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/10.2.6/play-services-location-10.2.6.pom'. Received status code 409 from server: Conflict
<a href="toggle.offline.mode">Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project</a>
```

But I never use play location anywhere.

Didn't found any solution. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The 409 error you are getting from Artifactory is a result of trying to resolve a release artifact from a snapshots repository (libs-snapshot-local). Looking at the URL in the error log you provided, it seems that you are working with the local libs-snapshot-local repository.
You can solve the issue by using a [virtual repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Virtual+Repositories), such as libs-snapshot, which aggregates your local snapshot repositories and remote repositories such as JCenter and Maven Central (for serving the request for play-services-location).

Comment: Thank you @Dror Berznitsky
I able to solve the problem.